# Need help in Parallelizing if and else condition in CUDA C program

Tags: image-processing, parallel-processing, cuda

I have written a filter for image blurring in C and it's working fine, I am  trying to run in on GPU using CUDA C for faster processing. The program has a few if and else conditions as can be seen below for the C code version,
  The input to the function being input image, output image, and size of columns.

```
  void convolve_young1D(double * in, double * out, int datasize) {
        int i, j;

    /* Compute first 3 output elements */
    out[0] = B*in[0];
    out[1] = B*in[1] + bf[2]*out[0];
    out[2] = B*in[2] + (bf[1]*out[0]+bf[2]*out[1]);

    /* Recursive computation of output in forward direction using filter parameters bf and B */
    for (i=3; i<datasize; i++) {
        out[i] = B*in[i];
        for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
            out[i] += bf[j]*out[i-(3-j)];
        }
    }

}
    //Calling function below
void convolve_young2D(int rows, int columns, int sigma, double ** ip_padded) {

        /** \brief Filter radius */
        w = 3*sigma;
        /** \brief Filter parameter q */
        double q;
        if (sigma < 2.5)
            q = 3.97156 - 4.14554*sqrt(1-0.26891*sigma);
        else
            q = 0.98711*sigma - 0.9633;

        /** \brief Filter parameters b0, b1, b2, b3 */
        double b0 = 1.57825 + 2.44413*q + 1.4281*q*q + 0.422205*q*q*q;
        double b1 = 2.44413*q + 2.85619*q*q + 1.26661*q*q*q;
        double b2 = -(1.4281*q*q + 1.26661*q*q*q);
        double b3 = 0.422205*q*q*q;

        /** \brief Filter parameters bf, bb, B */
        bf[0] = b3/b0; bf[1] = b2/b0; bf[2] = b1/b0;
        bb[0] = b1/b0; bb[1] = b2/b0; bb[2] = b3/b0;
        B = 1 - (b1+b2+b3)/b0;

        int i,j;

        /* Convolve each row with 1D Gaussian filter */
        double  *out_t = calloc(columns+(2*w),sizeof(double ));
        for (i=0; i<rows+2*w; i++) {
            convolve_young1D(ip_padded[i], out_t, columns+2*w);
         }
    free(out_t);
```

Tried the same approach with blocks and threads in CUDA C but wasn't  successful I have been getting zeros as output and even the input values seem to change to Zeros don't know where I am going wrong please do help. I am pretty new to CUDA C programming. Here is my attempted version of the  CUDA Kernel.

```
__global__ void convolve_young2D( float *in, float *out,int rows,int columns, int j,float B,float bf[3],int w) {

int k;

int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

if((x>0) && (x<(rows+2*w))) 
{
//printf("%d \t",x);

if(j ==0)
{
 // Compute first output elements  
 out[x*columns] = B*in[x*columns];
}

else if(j==1)
{ 
  out[x*columns +1 ] = B*in[x*columns +1] + bf[2]*out[x*columns];
}
else if (j== 2)
 {
   out[2] = B*in[x*columns +2] + (bf[1]*out[x*columns]+bf[2]*out[x*columns+1]);
 }  
else{
 //  Recursive computation of output in forward direction using filter parameters bf and B 
       out[x*columns+j] = B*in[x*columns+j];
        for (k=0; k<3; k++) {
            out[x*columns + j] += bf[k]*out[(x*columns+j)-(3-k)];
         }
    }
 }   

}

//Calling function below
void convolve_young2D(int rows, int columns, int sigma, const float * const ip_padded, float * const op_padded) {   
 float bf[3], bb[3];
 float  B;
 int w;

    /** \brief Filter radius */

    w = 3*sigma;
    /** \brief Filter parameter q */
    float q;
    if (sigma < 2.5)
        q = 3.97156 - 4.14554*sqrt(1-0.26891*sigma);
    else
        q = 0.98711*sigma - 0.9633;
    /** \brief Filter parameters b0, b1, b2, b3 */
    float b0 = 1.57825 + 2.44413*q + 1.4281*q*q + 0.422205*q*q*q;
    float b1 = 2.44413*q + 2.85619*q*q + 1.26661*q*q*q;

    float b2 = -(1.4281*q*q + 1.26661*q*q*q);
    float b3 = 0.422205*q*q*q;
 /** \brief Filter parameters bf, bb, B */
    bf[0] = b3/b0; bf[1] = b2/b0; bf[2] = b1/b0;
    bb[0] = b1/b0; bb[1] = b2/b0; bb[2] = b3/b0;
    B = 1 - (b1+b2+b3)/b0;      
   int p;
 const int inputBytes = (rows+2*w) * (columns+2*w) * sizeof(float);
 float *d_input, *d_output; // arrays in the GPU´s global memory
cudaMalloc(&d_input, inputBytes);
cudaMemcpy(d_input, ip_padded, inputBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMalloc(&d_output,inputBytes);
for (p = 0; p<columns+2*w; p++){
convolve_young<<<4,500>>>(d_input,d_output,rows,columns,p,B,bf,w);
}
cudaMemcpy(op_padded, d_input, inputBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaFree(d_input);
```

Comment: My tip would be to use the same code on CPU and GPU. Then you can test your implementation with #pragma openmp parallel for before mirgrating it to cuda.

Comment: If you want help, you will need to provide an [MCVE]. I can't tell you what the problem is without seeing a short complete example I can compile, run and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply dari, I don't  know much about #pragma openmp parallel from what I read now it says it's a simple C/C++/Fortran compiler extension that allows to add parallelism into existing source code, but my doubt is that it says the thread creation for Openmp is time consuming and my purpose of porting to GPU is to accelerate the program. And does Openmp utilize the threads in the GPU?

Comment: @talonmies I will paste the link for the complete executable of the program in a while, sorry for not having the complete information above.

Comment: @SuhasS: That isn't what I asked for. Don't paste things at links. Edit the shortest code which is compileable and reproduces your problem into your question.

Comment: @talonmies: Sure sir will do it.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you call `convolve_young<<<4,500>>>(d_input,d_output,rows,columns,p,B,bf,w);` but you defined a kernel named convolve_young**2D**.

Another possible problem is that to do the convolution you do:

```
for (p = 0; p<columns+2*w; p++){
    convolve_young<<<4,500>>>(d_input,d_output,rows,columns,p,B,bf,w);
}
```

Here you're looping over the columns instead of the rows compared to the CPU algorithm:

```
for (i=0; i<rows+2*w; i++) {
    convolve_young1D(ip_padded[i], out_t, columns+2*w);
}
```

First you should try to do a direct port of your CPU algorithm, computing one line at the time, and then modify it to transfer the whole image.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't sent the edited version of the code, I will update it here now. Thanks for the reply.